# android 8 (API 26) : WebView issue : err_unsafe_port for http://xxxxxx:6666 for example

Tags: android, android-webview, android-8.0-oreo

Apparently android added a port check to the WebVeiw APIs. 
I am not able to find in the net any way to open a http link in a webview in android 8 (API 26). It's always showing: err_unsafe_port.

I really need to work with this on dev environment. Do you have any solution or workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only I would suggest is to create a server size port redirection 6666 > 80